# The same row returns multiple times

Tags: sql-server, inner-join, union

Currently, I have three ports in use in a switch and i'm trying to monitor the traffic with the SQL below.

```
select a.interface, a.utilization_in, b.utilization_out from
(select z.source as interface, y.samplevalue as utilization_in from #TABLE1 z
join #TABLE2 y
on z.table_id = y.table_id
where z.source = 'switch1' and z.port like 'port_in%') a

INNER JOIN

(select x.source as interface, w.samplevalue as utilization_out from #TABLE1 x
join #TABLE2 w 
on x.table_id = w.table_id
where x.source = 'switch1' and x.port like 'port_out%') b
on a.interface=b.interface
```

This gets me the result, but each row is repeated several times, 3*3 = 9. I have been searching around and found that some use the union operator. But i'm lost in where to even put it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A union means that you have two seperate SELECT queries that have the same number of columns and that you present the result of both as one result set.

So basically it is this:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...

UNION 

SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...
```

Remember that a `UNION` will perform a `distinct` as well, so it doesn't return duplicate rows. If you don't want the distinct, use `UNION ALL`

Comment: That doesn't give him what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
select z.source as interface, y.samplevalue as utilization_in from #TABLE1 z
join #TABLE2 y
on z.table_id = y.table_id
where z.source = 'switch1' and z.port like 'port_in%'

UNION ALL -- or use just UNION if there are could be duplicates in both parts

select x.source as interface, w.samplevalue as utilization_out from #TABLE1 x
join #TABLE2 w 
on x.table_id = w.table_id
where x.source = 'switch1' and x.port like 'port_out%'
```

but as you have the same join conditions and the only difference is in port then you might use following query:

```
select z.source as interface, y.samplevalue as utilization, CASE WHEN z.port like 'port_in%' THEN 'IN' ELSE 'OUT' END as in_or_out
from #TABLE1 z
join #TABLE2 y
on z.table_id = y.table_id
where z.source = 'switch1'
```

Comment: But that doesn't supply what he wanted. `Interface | uti_in | uti_out`

Comment: it does (at least the query with no unions) by providing new column

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation , that way you only select from the tables once:

```
select x.source as interface, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN x.port like 'port_out%' THEN w.samplevalue END) as utilization_out,
       MAX(CASE WHEN x.port like 'port_in%' THEN w.samplevalue END) as utilization_in
from #TABLE1 x
join #TABLE2 w 
 on x.table_id = w.table_id
where x.source = 'switch1' 
GROUP BY x.source
```